# Fubini application

Tags: measure-theory

I used fubini's Thm several times. Now I am learning for a measure theory course and I suddenly have doubts..

How to check for a function $f$ on a product space $E \times F$ That she is in $L^1(E \times F)$?

Is it right to check that the integral is finite and the same for both Integral directions (on E then F & on F then E)?
Would this prove the assumption $L^1(E \times F)$?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please specify a little more regarding the context? I presume $f$ isn't necessarily positive; are you asking regarding $\int|f|$ or $\int f$? Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that, $f\in L^{1}(E\times F) $ iff $\int_{E\times F} |f(x, y)| dx dy < \infty$; and to checking this conditions some times Tonelli's theorem

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem)

is useful.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Is it right what you wrote? I always did it too but by definition shouldn't it be like $f\in L^1(E\times F)$ iff $\int_{E\times F} |f(x,y)|d\nu(x,y)$? So checking that the integral is finite without splitting the integral on two measures (wrto $\nu(x,y)$)

Comment: I find Tonelli more helpful. I just want to make clear this problem on the condition :)